# TestNG.XML not executing.when run via maven -mvn test - even after proper configurations in POM.XML

Tags: java, xml, maven, selenium, testng

This is my first question in StackOverflow, so please forgive if the question is not accurate.

I created a maven project. Trying to run TestNG.XML through maven but the same is not working. Getting below output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< MavenTestDemo:MavenTestDemo >---------------------
[INFO] Building MavenTestDemo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MavenTestDemo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ MavenTestDemo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ MavenTestDemo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MavenTestDemo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\sneha\eclipse-workspace\MavenTestDemo\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) @ MavenTestDemo ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.458 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-07T18:26:56+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The test cases are not executing just showing Build success. But when I try to run TestNG.xml with TestNG suite, the same is running properly.

When I give class name as "Demo1Test.java" then code runs as expected but always we can't give name ending with Test.

Please find my TestNG.xml and POM.xml files below:

**TestNG.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="maven test">
<test name="TestNG testing">
<packages>
<package name="com.qa.tests.*"/>
</packages>
</test>
</suite>
```

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MavenTestDemo</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenTestDemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>

        <configuration>
        <suiteXMLFiles>
       <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                <suiteXMLFile>src/test/resources/TestNG.xml</suiteXMLFile>
                </suiteXMLFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>  
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
  <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
  </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Can you please provide me insight on these.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see Maven compiler plugin.

```
   <!-- Compiler plugin configures the java version to be usedfor compiling the code --> 

<plugin> 
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
    <configuration> 
    <source>1.6</source> 
    <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration> 
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Even after placing compiler and source plugin, test cases are not executing.